# Ошибка во flask: TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: python, flask

Есть вот такая вот функция:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@oid.loginhandler
def login():
    if g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated(): # ошибка тут
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['remember_me'] = form.remember_me.data
        return oid.try_login(form.openid.data, ask_for=['nickname', 'email'])

    return render_template('login.html',
                           title='Sign In',
                           form=form,
                           providers=app.config['OPENID_PROVIDERS'])
```

В процессе исполнения в строке

`if g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated():`

возникает ошибка

`TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable`.

Не понимаю в чем дело...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `g.user.is_authenticated` (без скобок).